# How to separate my Aggregates by using EF DbContext in DDD

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, dbcontext

I have 5 domains and i need to separate each domain with different database,so how can I do that separation using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domain driven design has no opinion on your persistence mechanism such as how you design or structure your database or databases. So from a DDD perspective, the answer is "however you like"!

But, if you would *like to* separate your domains into different databases (even though you don't have to) your options are:

1. Keep everything across all your domains in one DbContext and pass interfaces into your classes that give access to only particular domain classes, such as IOrdersRepository that accesses Orders from the DbContext, and an IInvoicesRepository that accesses only Invoices from the same DbContext.
2. Add multiple DbContexts to your app for each domain, like SalesDbContext, BillingDbContext, MarketingDbContext and give each DbContext its own connection string in your Startup.cs file.
3. Split your app into smaller projects (like microservices) like a Sales.Api with its own DbContext, and a Billing.Api with its own DbContext.

There may be other options I haven't thought of too, seeing as DDD doesn't prescribe anything about how you store your data.

Comment: 2. Add multiple DbContexts for each app, I do some thing like this `public class AdministrationDbContext : DbContext{...} ` and `public class AccountingDbContext: DbContext{...} `  Etc, but now when i try to migrate each DbContext to the db it build all the Aggregates in each DB.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I think your domains are too tightly coupled to each other. I guess that your models in each context reference models in another context, so EFCore is building a big relational database with lots of tables with foreign keys referencing other tables... is that what you mean? You can actually build apps like this if you want. But if you have decided to separate your domains then you'll need to decouple those contexts from each other.

Comment: I like to listen/read Derek Comartin. He talks a lot about finding boundaries and separating domains and bounded contexts within DDD. Maybe this video or one of his others will help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnhshUdRW70&t=2074s

Comment: super useful, thanks.